# DNS - Multiple records

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I'm having an issue changing the DNS records for my domain.

Currently my DNS configuration is as follows:

```
domain.global      A      165.227.196.94
www.robbu.global      CNAME     robbu.global

inveniolive.robbu.global      A      206.189.206.222
www.inveniolive.robbu.global      CNAME      inveniolive.robbu.global
```

The DNS settings for the `165.227.196.94` IP address are working properly.

However for the `206.189.206.222`IP address are not working. I receive the following error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
inveniolive.robbu.global’s server IP address could not be found.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I can not have multiple A records?

How should I configure my DNS?

Comment: But the error you posted is for the first domain (`domain.global`) which you say is working properly and not for the second one..

Comment: @HumbertoCastellon edited

Comment: can you post the query you typed for the error message you're getting?

Comment: @HumbertoCastellon just enter the url on any browser: `inveniolive.robbu.global`

Comment: where does the `inveniolive.robbu.global` subdomain resides? internal server or hosting?

Comment: @HumbertoCastellon In a DigitalOcean droplet, both use differente droplets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85849/discussion-between-humberto-castellon-and-caio-kawasaki).

Comment: Please click the link above to move to the chat so we you can provide more details and try to give a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I see your scenario, you should have your DNS records to look something like this:

```
    robbu.global      A      165.227.196.94
    www.robbu.global            CNAME   robbu.global

inveniolive.robbu.global            A       206.189.206.222
www.inveniolive.robbu.global    CNAME   inveniolive.robbu.global
```

You need to check with your DNS provider that your records are created correctly because seeing that error means the domain name you're querying isn't resolving or doesn't even exist [image: ( I confirmed this by doing a simple nslookup)]  but (as you confirmed it) the site is reachable by IP address. Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: I did not understand what I should do =(